# How to write SQL query without join?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Recently during an interview I was asked a question: if I have a table like as below:

[image]

The requirement is: how many orders and how many shipments per day (based on date column) - output needs to be like this:

[image]

I have written the following code, but interviewer ask me to write a SQL query without JOIN and UNION, achieve the same output.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.order_date, b.ship_date), orders, shipments 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         order_date, COUNT(1) AS orders 
     FROM 
         table 
     GROUP BY 1) a
FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT
         ship_date, COUNT(1) AS shipments 
     FROM table) b ON a.order_date = b.ship_date
```

Is this possible? Could you guys please advice?

Comment: No need for a join. GROUP BY and use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Colud you please provide example code

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNION` and `GROUP BY` with conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FLAG = 'ORDER' THEN 1 END) AS ORDERS,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN FLAG = 'SHIP' THEN 1 END) AS SHIPMENTS
 FROM (SELECT ORDER_DATE AS DATE_, 'ORDER' AS FLAG FROM YOUR_TABLE
       UNION ALL
       SELECT SHIP_DATE AS DATE_, 'SHIP' AS FLAG FROM YOUR_TABLE) T
```

Comment: is this possible without UNION?

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, I would express this as:

```
select date, countif(n = 0) as orders, countif(n = 1) as numships
from t cross join
     unnest(array[order_date, ship_date]) date with offset n
group by 1
order by date;
```

The advantage of this approach (over `union all`) is two-fold.  First, it only scans the table once.  More importantly, the `unnest()` is all on the same node where the data resides -- so data does not need to be moved for the unpivot.